# How to use bridge for CLLocationCoordinate2D

Tags: objective-c, struct, cllocation, bridge

AM trying to add CLLocationCoordinate2D[] to NSMutableArray and send it as parameter. But (__bridge id) is crashing the app. Struct to id conversion is the problem. Could anyone please let me know how to use this please.

CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[1000];

coordinates[index] --- all the coordinates added to it in loop.

```
NSMutableArray *coorArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[coorArray addObject:(__bridge id)(coordinates)]; crashes here
```

Comment: If I understand correctly, you want to create an array of arrays of CLLocationCoordinate2D?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
NSMutableArray *coorArray = [NSMutableArray array];
[coorArray addObject:[NSValue valueWithPointer:coordinates]];
```

Then when you want to retrieve the array of struct:

```
CLLocationCoordinate2D coordinates[] = [coorArray objectAtIndex:0].pointerValue;
```

A C array is not an object, so it can't be bridged.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at `+[NSValue valueWithBytes:objCType:]` not a (__bridge) cast. Bridge is for other things.

e.g.:
`[NSValue value:&coordinate withObjCType:@encode(CLLocationCoordinate2D)];`

I guess it's possible to encode whole array too

Comment: No in this case coordinates is an array of CLLocationCoordinate2D.

Comment: I accepted Rikkles answer since it was exactly what I wanted. still I should give you one UP for your effort to help me. Thank you.